# Downloading videos with Safari 7.0.1 on OS X mavericks

Tags: macos, safari

In previous versions of Mac OS X, one could download videos in Safari with <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>. How can this be done in Safari 7.0.1 on a OS X mavericks?

Comment: Does it download videos in a certain format (e.g. .mov, Flash) or all videos?

Answer (score 24):

Option-command-A is just a shortcut for showing the resources tab of the web inspector. It still works, but you have to enable the develop menu first.

1. Check Preferences > Advanced > Show Develop menu in menu bar.
2. Open the resources tab of the web inspector.
3. Look for a resource for the video under the other folder. It's named `videoplayback` in YouTube. If it doesn't show up, try reloading the page.
4. Double-click the resource to open it.
5. Focus the location bar and press option-return to download the video. If you try to save the page, Safari only saves an empty file.

Note that some sites like twitch.tv use multiple resources for long videos.

Another option is to use `youtube-dl`. You can install it with `brew install youtube-dl` after installing [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Some examples:

`youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234567`

`youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1234567 --extract-audio`

`youtube-dl http://www.twitch.tv/b/1234567 -o ~/Downloads/'%(uploader)s %(title)s %(id)s.%(ext)s'`

`pbpaste|grep -o 'https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=[0-9]*'|parallel youtube-dl -o '%(id)s %(title)s.%(ext)s'`

`curl -s http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/someusername/uploads|grep -o 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=[^&]*'|sort -u|parallel youtube-dl`

Comment: `youtube-dl` is also available in MacPorts